# Prove that $p$ and $q$ are logically equivalent if and only if $p\leftrightarrow q$ is a tautology.

Tags: proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus

Can someone please verify whether my proof is okay? It looks very tedious and possibly stating unnecessary statements. I might also be missing some important facts.

> Prove that $p$ and $q$ are logically equivalent if and only if $p\leftrightarrow q$ is a tautology.

Assume $p$ is logically equivalent to $q$. Then every truth value gives $p$ and $q$ the same truth values. Then $p\leftrightarrow q$ is a tautology.

Assume $p\leftrightarrow q$ is a tautology. Then $p$ and $q$ have the same truth values. Then it must be that $p$ is logically equivalent to $q$.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by logically equivalent? The statement you are trying to prove seems true to me by definition.

Comment: @Hugocito Logically equivalent: $p \Leftrightarrow q$. Yes, the definition of logically equivalent proves it is a tautology already! So I am just wondering whether my proof is too tedious?

Comment: Correct; see [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence#Relation_to_material_equivalence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Assume p is logically equivalent to q. Then every truth value gives p and q the same truth values."

That sounds fine.  'p' and 'q' have the same truth value by definition.

"Then p↔q is a tautology."

You might do better to refer to the values of ($\bot$↔$\bot$) and ($\top$↔$\top$) specifically.  And you might do well to note that no other truth values than $\top$ and $\bot$ exist for how ↔ gets understood, because there exist three-valued logical systems where there exist connectives for a similar concept, but the same truth values for both 'p' and 'q' do not guarantee that (p↔q) is a tautology.

The same goes for the second part.